# Quadratic forms and Cholesky factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that K is a full ranked $n\times n$ real matrix and $A$ is an orthonormal matrix of dimension $n\times k$. We know that the matrix $A^T K^T K A$ is symmetric and positive definite so the uniqueness of the Cholesky decomposition implies that it can be written as $L^T L$ with $L$ and $k\times k$ matrix.

My question is: Can we write $L$ in terms of $A$ and $K$?

Comment: My main concern is that we can write $L = CKA$ with any $C$ that $C^TC = I_k$ but this contradicts the fact that $L$ is unique!

Comment: Explanation of the pseudo-contradiction: L has to be **upper triangular**, thus is by no means equal to $CKA$...

Comment: Can't be any $C$ such that $C^TC = I_k$, because the diagonal entries of $L$ has to be positive. I'm not saying this solves the problem, but the Cholesky factorization says $L$ is lower triangular with positive diagonal entries, this has to be considered.

Comment: You are absolutely right @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite easy actually. If $K^TK$ has the Cholesky factorization $R^TR$ then

$A^TK^T K A = A^TR^T R  A = A^T R^T A A^T RA = L^TL$

since $L = A^TRA$ is upper triangular then it must be the Cholesky factorization of $A^TK^T K A$.